# Default enum value in javascript class constructor

Tags: javascript, class, enums

I have a simple class, and I'm trying to figure out how to set a default value in the constructor:

```
var Foo = function(bar = Foo.someEnum.VAL1) {

    this.bar = bar;
    someEnum = {VAL1 : 1, VAL2: 2};
}
```

and to use it like:

```
var myFoo = new Foo(Foo.someEnum.VAL1);
```

but this is apparently wrong. What's the correct way to set a default enum value, or do I need to set the default to null, and check for the null in the constructor and set accordingly?

To clarify, bar is an enum for the Foo class. There are other properties in the class that are not shown. Also, updated class code.

Comment: It would be helpful to post what the expected result of your function is, and the way you'd like to call it

Comment: I just want to point out that when you do `var Foo = function()`, you are creating a brand new variable named Foo with nothing in it. So there is no such thing as Foo.someEnum.VAL1 at that point.

Comment: @millerbr updated and, it's a class.

Comment: It's not a class. In ES6, a class is defined with `class className()`, and it doesn't exist in anything before ES6 - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @millerbr over the very latest browsers currently support classes, so they're of no use to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you want to make bar an *optional parameter*:

```
function Foo(bar) {
    this.bar = bar || Foo.enum.VAL1; //If bar is null, set to enum value.
}

//Define static enum on Foo.
Foo.enum = { VAL1: 1, VAL2: 2, VAL3: 3 };

console.log(new Foo().bar); //1
console.log(new Foo(Foo.enum.VAL3).bar); //3
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `bar` to be defined inside the function?

```
var Foo = function() {
    var bar = {VAL1 : 1, VAL2: 2};
}
```

or for a blank starting object:

```
var Foo = function() {
    var bar = {};
}
```

Or are you wanting it to be set from a parameter that's passed into the function?

```
var Foo = function(barIn) {
    var bar = barIn;
}
```

Another option - create the object (enum) from values passed in:

```
var Foo = function(val1, val2) {
    var bar = {VAL1 : val1, VAL2: val2};
}
```

The possibilities go on, but it's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do but maybe it is this...

```
var Foo = function (bar = 1) {
    this.bar = bar;
}
Foo.VAL1 = 1;
Foo.VAL2 = 2;
```

Now you can do:

```
foo1 = new Foo();
alert(foo1.bar); //alerts 1;

foo2 = new Foo(Foo.VAL2);
alert(foo1.bar); //alerts 2;
```